# Is Pokemon Sun and Moon's story new or a continuation?

Tags: pokemon

Okay, I just saw lately the new Pokemon Sun and Moon anime series. I guess you're already familiar with the characters. In the new series, Ash's design is different from what we all know spiky black hair (etc).

Is the Sun and Moon series a new different pokemon story (like Red's series or a story of an alternate world) because the Ash looks different or it's another continuation where Ash just changed his look?

Comment: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:Ash_SM.png Seems like Ash and Pikachu to me. Clearly its the continuation of Ash and Pikachu

Comment: @Arcane Yeah, but Ash looks change a bit. Just a bit. I dunno if it's because the people behind the Alola series or just making a new fresh look. The drawing style is a bit Studio Ghibli-sh. Hehe. Holy moly, look at this Team Rocket's http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:Team_Rocket_trio_SM.png

Comment: That is true for all the characters. Even Oak. Design changes have been known to occur from Pokemon region to region. When I used to watch it, Ash went on looking a bit mature from Kanto, Johto, and Hoenn. But then from Sinnoh onwards I feel he was "reset". The design changes were more obvious in Unova, Kalos and now in Alola.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, there is a drastic change in art style compared to the XY&Z series. Also, Ash is depicted more as a comedic character compared to his character in XY&Z. One interesting factor to note here is that unlike all the other series before, anything related to Kalos or Ash's adventure there hasn't been mentioned even once.

However, based on Pikachu's move set, we know for sure that it's post Unova. And another interesting thing to note is during the episode where the characters visit Kanto, during the battle between Brock and Kiawe. Ash had prior knowledge on Mega evolutions while the rest of the characters didn't know what it was. Ash came to know of the same during his time in Kalos.

I guess it's up to to the writers to decide based on how they want to continue the series in the future.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Yes, it's the same Ash, the new series prove it by showing his Kalos badges alongside the Manalo Conference Trophy (Episode 2)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Stanley and Gary. It continues series after Pokemon x y and z. it is not any new series. The best proof is the mega evolution of brock and misty pokemon where the characters visit Kanto.

> Pokemon Sun & Moon Episode 43 - Gym Battle! Z-Move vs Mega Evolution!!

You must be thinking when ash is so strong why he joined the pokemon school in Alola? well, ash do not have any knowledge about the Alola region, that is why to learn about Alola Pokemon he joined Pokemon school.

well, it seems like ash is not getting old but you cannot define age of anyone in any manga or tv series.

> Pikachu also knows all the previous moves he learned before like an iron tale,
>   electro web that is another evidence.